# Why does not api.depends work with the message_follower_ids field on non edit mode? How to fix it?

Tags: python, python-2.7, odoo, odoo-10, odoo-view

I want to show a message when I have follower in the document and they are not users of Odoo. So I created two computed fields, one for the message and another one to check if the message should be shown.

```py
class SaleOrder(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'sale.order'

    @api.multi
    @api.depends('message_follower_ids')
    def _compute_show_warning_msg(self):
        partner_ids = self.env['res.users'].search([])\
            .mapped('partner_id').mapped('id')
        for record in self:
            msg = _("""\nDocument contains no user followers.\n""")
            for follower in record.message_follower_ids:
                if follower.partner_id.id not in partner_ids:
                    record.show_warning_msg = True
                    record.warning_msg = msg

    show_warning_msg = fields.Boolean(
        compute='_compute_show_warning_msg',
        string='Show warning message',
    )

    warning_msg = fields.Text(
        compute='_compute_show_warning_msg',
        string='Warning message',
    )
```

But when the form is not in edit mode and I add or remove followers the compute method is not triggered. So I must press the "Edit" button and the "Save" to trigger the method.

I have tried to execute the compute method on the create and unlink methods of the follower table, but the form view is not refreshed

Is there a way to trigger the compute field and refresh the form in order to show the message?

Any workaround or fix?

Comment: I think you need to see how to trigger this in javascript because the problem is there. but one thing don't you think if you use seach_read is better. instead of search than mapped to time?

Comment: OK, thanks, I will take a look at the JavaScript. And yes, you may right, the `search_read` could be faster. But the `res_users` table usually has only a few records and using `mapped` I get a list of ids in a more convenient way.

Comment: @Cherif I found a more elegant solution to the problem, check my answer if you are interested in

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A possible solution, I added this code to the form view:

```
<field name="message_follower_ids" position="attributes">
    <attribute name="class">oe_edit_only</attribute>
</field>
```

Answer (score 1):

The button to add followers look like this:

```html
<button aria-expanded="false" class="btn btn-sm btn-link dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" title="Ningún seguidor">
    <i class="fa fa-user"></i>
    <span class="o_followers_count">0</span>
    <span class="caret"></span>
</button>
```

So I just added the class `oe_edit_only` to the button and problem fixed. The user has to be in edit mode to see the button and to add or remove followers:

```html
<button aria-expanded="false" class="btn btn-sm btn-link dropdown-toggle oe_edit_only" data-toggle="dropdown" title="Ningún seguidor">
    <i class="fa fa-user"></i>
    <span class="o_followers_count">0</span>
    <span class="caret"></span>
</button>
```

Comment: LoooooL this why i love coding. don't complicate things i learned this the hard way spend three days solving a problem by editing the javascript in report to prevent the header from showing in the second page on the report. after solving it then i found another solution that don't require 5 minute of code thank for the idea